# Unable to stop handler despite calling removeCallbacks(runnable)

Tags: android

I have been trying to stop a handler in my onPause(). Despite of calling removeCallbacks(timeRunnable) or removeCallbacksAndMessages(timeRunnable), the handler is not stopped. I have seen many answers here. But nothing worked. I might be missing something here.

**Code:**

```
public Runnable timeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("Here is my task");
        timeHandler.postDelayed(timeRunnable, 5000);
    }
};

public void startTimeHandler() {
    timeHandler.post(timeRunnable);
}

public void stopTimeHandler() {
    timeHandler.removeCallbacks(timeRunnable);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopTimeHandler();
}
```

Comment: By "the handler is not stopped", do you mean that `timeRunnable` executes anyway after onPause?

Comment: @RyanM Yes. It doesn’t stop .

Comment: @Kumza ion are you sure onPause is being called?

Comment: @kumza Ion, onPause() gets called immediately when your app goes to the background from foreground. Also, the logs should stop appearing then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using below code snippet to run a thread every 10 seconds and update UI based on the values received from Server, stop thread on onPause.

Declare below variables in your class:

```
public class ActivityPortfolio extends AppCompatActivity {
  Handler handler = new Handler();
  Runnable runnable;
  int delay = 10*1000;
 //---------
```

In your onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

                doSomething();
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);

    super.onResume();
}
```

onPause():

```
  @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable); // this alone didnt work as we are calling postDelayed() in background as well.
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);//after adding this it stops thread
}
```